# Adding a legend manually for a plot generated by a loop

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I am generating a plot in Matlab one point at a time depending on how a condition is satisfied within a loop:

```
for i=1:size(Ind,1)
    if(Ind(i)==1)
        c='ro';
    elseif(Ind(i)==2)
        c='bo';
    elseif(Ind(i)==3) 
        c='go';
    end
     plot(i,Y(i),c) %plotting some other value with the color chosen.
     hold on
  end
```

How do I add a legend entry to this? I want to associate the index position(1,2 and 3) to red,blue and green in the legend.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow generally should contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code that you have posted is not complete nor verifiable. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35005346/edit) your question to ensure that the code in your question is **Minimal** (only the code necessary to reproduce), **Complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **Verifiable** (we should be able to reproduce the issue using only the code in your question, nothing less and nothing more).

Comment: I'd try using scatter instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating theoretically a large number of plot objects, it is much better to either create 3 plot objects (one of each color) or create a gscatter plot. MATLAB is notoriously slow with dealing with a large number of plot objects.

**Create 3 plot objects (red, green, blue)**

```
Ind = ceil(rand(100,1) * 3);
Y = rand(100,1);

figure;
red_plots = plot(find(Ind == 1), Y(Ind == 1), 'ro', 'DisplayName', 'red');
hold on;
blue_plots = plot(find(Ind == 2), Y(Ind == 2), 'go', 'DisplayName', 'green');
green_plots = plot(find(Ind == 3), Y(Ind == 3), 'bo', 'DisplayName', 'blue');
title('Three Plots')

legend([red_plots, blue_plots, green_plots])
```

[image]

**Create a [gscatter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gscatter.html) plot**

```
figure;
s = gscatter(1:size(Ind, 1), Y, Ind);
set(s, 'Marker', 'o')
title('Scatter')
legend({'red', 'green', 'blue'})
```

[image]

If you don't have the stats toolbox where `gscatter` is, then you can always use vanilla [`scatter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html)

```
figure;
s = scatter(1:size(Ind, 1), Y, 'CData', Ind, 'Marker', 'o');
title('Scatter')
colormap(eye(3));
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. And plotting it many times just didn't feel right. Thank you for the alternate solutions as well!

Comment: just a quick follow up question (assuming I use the first method by creating 3 plot objects): what if there are no entries in `Ind` matching 3. Then it won't be displayed in the legend at all. How do I force to show the color blue in the legend?

Comment: I recommend setting the "DisplayName" property instead of putting the legend together manually - that way, if you turn off the legend and turn it back on, it still has the right name.

Comment: @kami: you can always plot `[NaN, NaN]`, which will plot nothing, but still create a legend entry.